# command "$(</token/ecr-token)" is not working in sh shell but working in bash , how we can make this command work in sh shell

Tags: linux, docker, shell, kubernetes, amazon-eks

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
                 --dry-run=client \
                 --docker-server="$ECR_REGISTRY" \
                 --docker-username=AWS \
                 --docker-password="$(</token/ecr-token)" \
                 -o yaml
```

file token/ecr-token is in place but still not able to populate in --docker-password

Comment: You have a leading `/` in `/token/ecr-token` so it won't try to read `token/ecr-token`

Comment: look in `/token/ecr-token` you will see a command or such, `$(<)` will load it then execute it and return a value

Comment: so --docker-password="$(<token/ecr-token)" is right way to read and execute

Comment: You said (in a comment on my answer) that `echo "$(<token/ecr-token)"` returns an empty response inside the container. Are you running the `kubectl create` command from inside this same container?

Comment: yes....` - /bin/sh
             - -ce
             - |-
               kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
                 --dry-run=client \
                 --docker-server="$ECR_REGISTRY" \
                 --docker-username=AWS \
                 --docker-password="$(</token/ecr-token)" \
                 --docker-password="token/ecr-token" \
                 -o yaml | kubectl apply -f - `

Answer (score 2):

The `$(< /path/to/a/file)` syntax is a special form of command substitution that is supported by several UNIX shells, including [ksh](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh-1.html) (Oracle online documentation), [bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution), and [zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution). It attempts to open the listed file and then reads the contents of that file in place of the `$(< ...)`. It is distinct from command substitution in that it does not execute the given file or its contents.

See more details at this UNIX & Linux Q/A: [Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189749/117549).

Note that your command specifies an *absolute* file path of `/token/ecr-token` but then later describe a *relative* path of `token/ecr-token`. If you're using a relative path in the command-line, that file will need to exist relative to your current working directory. Of course, the file must be readable by the current user for the contents to be read.

If your shell does not support this feature, a workaround is to use `$(cat /path/to/a/file)`, for instance:

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry "$SECRET_NAME" \
                 --dry-run=client \
                 --docker-server="$ECR_REGISTRY" \
                 --docker-username=AWS \
                 --docker-password="$(cat /token/ecr-token)" \
                 -o yaml
```

Comment: i am inside the container and doing cat token/ecr-token. and able to see token but when  i am doing this... echo "$(<token/ecr-token)" getting the empty response @Jeff Schaller.  and  using this command to get inside the container `kubectl exec -it ecr-credentials-sync-init-lfs6r -c create-secret sh -n flux-system`.  so basically using sh

Comment: is there any way to read and execute in sh not bash or any other  shell

Comment: That sounds like a different question than "what is the meaning of `$(< /token/ecr-token)`", but -- [questions are free!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: i just want to read and execute from Sh shell  `kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \ --dry-run=client \ --docker-server="$ECR_REGISTRY" \ --docker-username=AWS \ --docker-password="$(</token/ecr-token)" ` ...How we can do this ..i am not able to find command substitution in SH shell ..so whats the best alternative

Comment: I attempted to answer your question as asked; if you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69409863/edit) your question to explain that you're unable to use this expansion in your current shell, me (or other answerers) could attempt to find out why & provide alternatives.